# Is it reasonable to leave a therapy session feeling worse?

Tags: clinical-psychology, depression

I apologize for (possibly) violating the only rule that shows up when you're about to ask a question: ask questions that can be answered rather than discussed.

But I'm hoping this question might actually have an answer, or at least some consensus, in case the answer is "no" (not specifically in this site - I'm hoping perhaps the answer can be found in some official guideline of a relevant organization of professionals).

A little background: It seems I've been suffering from depression for at least 10 years. I've been in therapy for about 4 months (Weekly).

After coming to my scheduled session in tears (which for me is extreme), we talked about why I was crying.
My problems have to do with the fact that my current reality is about as far as it can be from what I've wanted to achieve all my life, which my therapist believes is impossible to achieve.

I've made it very clear to him that he has a lot more work to do before he can convince me that what I want is unreasonable.

When I left my therapy session, I began to process what we talked about, and I felt worse than I did coming into the session.

While I can understand that doing anything else but discussing that subject and telling me that my goals are unreasonable would (probably, and at least in his opinion) do more harm than good, I can't help but wonder, especially since this isn't the first time he made me feel worse (well, only the second time I believe), if, in such a situation, one should seek another therapist, or to weather the storm.

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE! As a therapist myself, I could give advice but it could be wrong as I don't know your case & therapy sessions. [For a number of reasons outlined in this meta post](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/502/why-was-my-self-help-question-closed-as-off-topic) we can not, and will not, give advice for any individual. If you have a question regarding your therapy sessions, you should speak to your therapist. For further information on how this site is supposed to work, what is on-topic or not, you can take the [tour], visit the [ask] page and [meta].

Comment: @ChrisRogers I attempted to provide as little detail as possible since I don't want answers specific to my therapy session. I do intend to speak with my therapist anyway, but I think I have my answer. Thank you.